# comparison between BO and qlikview

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, business-objects, qlikview

I don't know if this would be coined as wrong place to ask this question. Recently, my company is thinking about getting qlikview for its BI instead of BO from SAP. Since I am in the team, I want to know how does two compare it terms of performance,graph functionalities and other additional features. Can anybody make some suggestions and/or point me to the source where I can find all these information?

Comment: I'm far more partial to stack-exchange sites in general, but having used both sites in the past, experts-exchange would probably be a better place to ask this particular question.  They're pretty good about catering to those kinds of application/frameworks/utilities/whatever.  They're okay with objective answers too which won't fly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using QlikView for just over a year now and it is extremely powerful.  They have just launched a new version as well.

have a look at the QlikTech website and in particular take a look through their on-site forum which is very active.  It would not surprise me if your comparison question has been asked already!?  I have read SAP being mentioned many times as i believe their is an SAP connector for it.

You can also download a fully functional personal edition from their website if you want to play about with it.

Some further reading about QlikView...

http://www.qlikblog.at/1384/set-analysis-wizard-qlikview/

http://www.qlikfix.com/

http://blog.qvapps.com/

http://qlikviewmaven.blogspot.co.uk/

http://www.qlikviewexamples.com/

http://www.quickqlearqool.nl/

http://qlikviewnotes.blogspot.co.uk/

http://robwunderlich.com/

http://www.qsgen.com/

http://www.quickintelligence.co.uk/

http://qliktips.blogspot.co.uk/2011_05_01_archive.html

http://www.rhyous.com/2009/11/30/my-new-and-improved-calendar-in-qlikview/

http://iqlik.wordpress.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx7b3k7y%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.qvexcel.com/

http://www.qvsource.com/

http://qlikdecision.blogspot.co.uk/

http://qlikboard.com/

hope that helps somewhat

Answer (score 0):

QlikView is rather unusual data visualization toolkit. It's a bit hard to compare it to SAP BO head-to-head (I've been working with both for several years), because SAP heavily relies on relational databases, but QlikView has its own ultra-fast in-memory data processing engine with very different ideology. I wrote a comparison of QlikView against "traditional" BI suites, like SAP BO which became rather popular: ["Busting 5 myths about QlikView"](http://bi-review.blogspot.com/2011/04/busting-5-myths-about-qlikview.html). Main points are:

- QlikView is very fast but limited with RAM size which limits its applicability for very large volumes of data
- QlikView deployment time usually is very short
- With QlikView you may still need Data Warehouse to clean up and consolidate data from various data sources (although QlikView has some basic ETL capabilities)
- QlikView is not a multi-purpose enterprise BI platform
- QlikView isn't that cheap

Another one point, missed in the article, is that QlikView allows creating very customizable user interface, more typical for rich interactive applications than for fancy but rigid chart builders.